# Type cast Fragment class to Context in android?

Tags: android

I am stuck up for quite long on a issue for which i dont find a solution.I have a expandable list view in a class that extends Fragment.I have made this view as public so that it can be accessible in the adapter class.I am passing my Arraylist and context to the adapter.In the adapter class i want to access the expandable list view.

```
Class MainFragment extends Fragment
{
  ...
  ...
  ArrayList<String>arrCategory=new ArrayList<String>();
  public ExpandableListView listview_categories;
  MainFragment_Adapter adapter;
  ....
   adapter=new MainFragment_Adapter(context, R.id.row_cell_text_multilevel, arrCategory);

}
```

In the adapter class

```
class MainFragment_Adapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter{

...
i am trying to access
if(!((MainFragment)context).listview_categories.isGroupExpanded(groupPosition)) 
{
  above if statement gives error
}
}
```

Error: Cannot cast from Context to MainFragment 
Can some one please tell me how do i access the public field listview_categories in the adaptor class?

Comment: to access the fragment from context you can use this.getFragmentManager().findFragmnetByTag("tag used on transaction").getExpandableListView().isGroupExpanded(position); and use a getter and setter for listView as private an other alternative you have is to pass the ExpandableListView on the constructor so you'll have access

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's clear, a Fragment is not a context. You could simple change the first parameter of you constructor to MainFragment.
And if you need a context, from a fragment, you do `myFragment.getActivity()`

Comment: I tried the above however it says "The method getactivity() is undefined for the type MainFragment"!